# Can I partially enable the fragment cache during development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller that renders images on the fly. The contents of the image depend entirely on the request, so it's very easy to cache it. I'd like to enable the fragment cache for just this controller (or action or cache block) during development, leaving it disabled for everything else in the app. Can this be done?

**Clarification**

General caching is very well documented, and I know you can enable and disable it with   config.action_controller.perform_caching. I'd like to enable it for only some cases while leaving it disabled for others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do fragment caching on rails using memcache. Take a look at this article that outlines various strategy for caching and how to implement fragment cache - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#fragment-caching

Comment: This is a useful document, but it doesn't address the question at hand. I've added a clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
config.assets.cache_store = :null_store  # Disables the Asset cache
config.sass.cache = false
```

it relies on that the fact that production assets are different.